# Connecting ZWO Camera with zwoasi

Tags: python, camera, astronomy

I've been trying to connect a ZWO camera with zwoasi, but when I try to get the ID of the connected camera I get

```
 "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 
 'ASIGetNumOfConnectedCameras'".
```

Does this mean the camera isn't connected properly? If so how do I assure it is connected? I also tried running an executable file using zwoasi and I got this error:

```
 The filename of the SDK library is required (or set 
 ZWO_ASI_LIB environment variable with the filename)
 An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
```

I'm running this on spyder 4.2.5 on a Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution was that I had to download the SDK from the zwoasi website:

https://astronomy-imaging-camera.com/software-drivers

under the "developers" tab

Answer (score 0):

I'll do my best to answer the second question, I think that it requires you to install SDK, or maybe find SDK and import it via path, first try

```
pip install sdk 

conda install sdk
```

depending on where your terminal is located

to import using path do this:

```
import importlib.util
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("module.name", "/path/to/file.py")
foo = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(foo)
foo.MyClass()
```

I can't help you beyond that because I am not familiar with the library, sorry. Let me know if you need anything else